# Map difference from Vega- Lite Topojson and UN map for Morocco and western Shara

Tags: dictionary, vega-lite, topojson, topojson2

We are using Vegalite to draw a global map, we have used the topo-json provided by Vega.

when we compared Morocco and Western maps generated from Vega Topo Json and the UN map of Morocco and Western Sahara, it was totally different.

UN Map
https://www.un.org/geospatial/content/africa-2

UN MAP for Morocco
https://www.un.org/geospatial/content/morocco

below are screenshots using Vegalite topo Json file ie. below URL

https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/world-map/

[Western Sahara](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvf7G.png)

[Morocco](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdD1O.png)

Need your help to modify the TopoJson to achieve similar to UN map shape for Morocco and Western Sahara.

We tried modifying pixel values, it is very complex, need your support to modify the TopoJson to achieve similar to UN map shape for Morocco and Western Sahara.

Answer (score 1):

Check visionscarto amended maps. They have adjusted the maps for Western Sahara, Crimea, Palestine etc based UN status.

https://observablehq.com/@visionscarto/world-atlas-topojson

https://github.com/visionscarto/world-atlas

Adam